# Spring-ws - I have a signed envelope that cannot be validated after being transformed in an endpointinterceptor

Tags: xml, transformation, spring-ws

I am creating a soap webservice using Spring-ws that must return a signed document.

We have other webservices (using Axis2) that use the same @Service classes that produce a complete signed envelope to be returned to the client.

The idea is to replace the axis2 webservice without requiring our customers clients to be updated, so the output from both Axis2 and Spring-ws should be the same and the clients must still be able to verify the document signature.

So I need to write the envelope I get from the @Service to the result the Spring-ws endpoint returns more or less untouched.

I thought this would be quite simple using an EndpointInterceptor, and get the SoapMessage from the MessageContext and then call tranformer.transform for each header and the body payload. This almost works - but unfortunately the signature breaks after being tranformed.

The only difference I see in the response from the new Spring-ws endpoint compared to the Envelope returned by the @Service class is that the namespace prefix for the envelope tag (and header and body) has changed from "s" to "soapenv".

I have created a small testclient - and if I replace soapenv with s in the received response the document signature can be verified.

Is there a way I can configure the Transformer/TransformerFactory to use specific prefixes for specific namespace-uri's I have missed in the docs?

If not then I would like to know how I can change the prefix on the Envelope, Header and Body tags. 
I know there is a SoapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration but that does not change the prefix as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was going in the wrong direction.

Since I had a complete Envelope already I could simply call soapMessage.setDocument(completeEnvelopeElementFromService.getOwnerDocument()) and skip using the Transformer for modifying my result altogether.